# change the date in ssis package for XML file

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis

I am working on SSIS in my XML file I have reading dates like 2013-08-02, 2013-08-4, 2013-08-05 but I have to change the data date to from last two days, What I mean is that the data date stamp should be changed to 2017-05-21,2017-05-22,2017-05-22.
  what I was done is added a derived column in the SSIS package and changed the expression with GETDATE() in this case I am getting only today date, But I need to change data from last two days.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you need, but have you tried the DATEDIFF expression? You should be able to calculate dates in your Derived Column Expression with that function. Use `DATEADD("d", -2, GETDATE())` to subtract 2 days from todays date.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DATEADD function to add or subtract time from a date. In your Derived Column, use this in the Expression field:

```
DATEADD("d", -2, GETDATE())
```

Note that this does subtract the time value as well so if you need to convert to strictly date format (or time zone conversions) you will need additional code.

Comment: <Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 08:30:00" RawReading="230.3"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-02 08:30:00" RawReading="229.9"/>

Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-03 17:00:00" RawReading="230.3"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-03 17:15:00" RawReading="229.9"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-03 17:30:00" RawReading="230.3"/>

<Reading TimeStamp="2013-08-03 17:45:00" RawReading="230.1"/ t

Comment: This is my data with different dates i have to change that dates into 5/22/2017,5/23/207 , what is the best way to do.

Comment: How  can I change the preserved dates  in the XML file to dates I required